# Prettier with Typescript

Tags: typescript, ember-cli

I am trying to add prettier to my project, but I cannot make it work with Typescript files. Prettier works fine on JS file, but it ignores TS files.

Do you have an idea what might be wrong?

Thanks

Here is my eslintrc file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaFeatures: {
            legacyDecorators: true
        }
    },
    plugins: ['ember'],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:ember/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    ],
    env: {
        browser: true
    },
    rules: {
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.ts'],
            extends: ['prettier'],
            plugins: ['prettier', '@typescript-eslint'],
            parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
        },

        // node files
        {
            files: [
                '.eslintrc.js',
                '.prettierrc.js',
                '.template-lintrc.js',
                'ember-cli-build.js',
                'testem.js',
                'blueprints/*/index.js',
                'config/**/*.js',
                'lib/*/index.js',
                'server/**/*.js'
            ],
            /// --- more config here ---
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have a file named .prettierignore ?

Comment: yes, I have prettierignore - *.ts files are not listed there

Comment: I figured it out - Intellij Idea was not configured properly

Comment: Ok good :) what did you change?

Comment: settings -> Languages & Framewoks -> Javascript -> Prettier -- I checked "On save" checkbox...